# Laravel Nova - Custom Card w/ Package

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I created a custom card in order to use [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick). This custom card will have a select dropdown which will make an Axios request to get data from an API and display it in the chart though my issue is the chart will not display even with hard-coded dummy data as can be seen below:

```html
<template>
    <card class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <span>Ben</span>
        <line-chart class="lcs" :data="chart_data"></line-chart>
    </card>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import Chartkick from "vue-chartkick";
import Chart from "chart.js";
Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart));
export default {
    props: ["card"],
    data() {
        return {
            chart_data: {
                "2017-05-13": 2,
                "2017-05-14": 5
            }
        };
    }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.flex {
    min-height: 950px;
}
</style>
```

The card is working and displaying on the dashboard. I simply placed span tags and output a name to confirm this as can be seen here:

[image]

I played with the CSS of the box to make sure the chart wasn't being hidden as can be seen from the changed shape.

I can't seem to get the chart to display and am unsure of what is being done wrong.

Comment: Where's the question here?

Comment: @Caddy DZ - The chart (<line-chart class="lcs" :data="chart_data"></line-chart>) isn't displaying.

Comment: Do you get no errors in the console?

Comment: Your code is working fine... Unable to reproduce, see [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-rjmz4)

Comment: @Caddy DZ - Unfortunately not, this is what is shown: https://i.imgur.com/Qo9WnET.png

Comment: The component is not rendered at all, did you compile your assets? `npm run dev`?

Comment: I navigated into the components folder, then OrdersByChart (the name of the custom card), and then did npm run dev followed by npm run watch and got that result in the screenshot.

Comment: Did you register your component in the nova service provider as per my answer below?

Comment: I registered it in the nova service provider previously (OrdersByChart): https://i.imgur.com/hs8Gtsi.png